# iOS Application Update Availability via "lookup' URL

Tags: ios, swift, itunes-store

I am using iTunes "lookup" URL for checking available app versions on iTunes store. The URL is in the format - `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=`. It works fine for apps available for all regions. But my application is only available across France iTunesStore. For that, I need to hardcode country code along with the URL i.e `&country=fr`.

Is there any way to avoid to do so, because hardcoding the country code will prevent the app to be detected by different region iTunes store if the app becomes scalable in near future.

Comment: go through with: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

Comment: @Rocky I checked but the content did not have any description or solution to my problem. Do you have any suggestions?